# poisson's equation with robin's boundary, boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

> Consider the Poisson’s equation with Robin’s boundary conditions as follows \begin{array}{ll}
> −\Delta u = f, &\text{in $U$,}\\
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}+u=g, &\text{on $\partial U$,}
> \end{array}
>   where $U$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\nu$ is the outward unit normal on $U$. Show that this boundary-value problem has at most one solution $u \in C^2(U) \cap C(\overline U)$.

I think I have to use the energy method but I'm really not sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please verify that my edits reflect your intended meaning.

Comment: yep, you're right- thanks! sorry, I'm not very good at the ol' latex lingo...

Comment: The only thing I really changed was replacing $\partial u$ with $\partial U$, because the latter seems more likely to be what you meant, but I don't know enough about this sort of math.

Comment: yep you were right :) just a typo

Comment: What is $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361423/variational-formulation-of-robin-boundary-value-problem-for-poisson-equation-in) of @ShuhaoCao, you can learn how to formulate this problem in a variation setting.

In this [link](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~amm456/Aaron%20Palmer.pdf), you can learn how to regularize it.

If you want to learn more about it, I suggest you to read section 4.11 of of this [book](http://www.amazon.ca/Sobolev-Spaces-V-G-MazJa/dp/0387135898) of Maz'ja. There you will discover that a interesting space to work with, is the completion of $$H^1(U)\cap C^{\infty}(U)\cap C(\overline{U})$$

with respect to the norm $$\|u\|_{1,2}+\|u\|_{L^{2}(\partial U)}$$

Then, if $W$ is such completion, you can easily see that the functional $I:W\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$I(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int_U |\nabla u|^2+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial U} u^2-\int_U fu$$

is strictly convex, coercive and weakly sequentially lower semicontinous, w.s.l.s.c. for short. Indeed the first item is evident. The coerciveness will follow because $W$ is continuously embedded in $L^2(U)$. The third item (w.s.l.s.c.) will follow because $W$ is compactly embedded in $L^2(U)$. Therefore, $I$ has a unique minimum in $W$ which is a solution of your problem.