# Weak formulation 1-D PDE with non-homogenous robin boundary condition

Tags: weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

Question:
[Question statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X33AN.png)

Worked Solution:
[Worked solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzdwV.png)

I have a few questions I hope you can help me with.
Firstly, is my weak formulation correct? Why can't I use a test function in $H^1_0$ space and use a lift function with the Robin b.c.?

Secondly, how do I prove continuity of B and F?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If $u\in H^1_0$, $u$ has zero value on the all boundary. However, in your problem, you have $u$ with non-zero boundary. That's why you cannot use a test function in $H^1_0$.

I think you can refer [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361423/315800).